# AngularFire and firebaseSimpleLogin forget my auth state

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I use AngularJS und Firebase to authenticate users in my app. The login process works like a charm, but when I refresh my page, it forgets the auth state and I need to login again. How do I make it "stick"? Code as follows:

```
.factory('loginService', ['$firebaseSimpleLogin', '$location', '$rootScope', 'firebaseurl',
  function($firebaseSimpleLogin, $location, $rootScope, firebaseurl) {
    return {
      login: function(email, pass, redirect, callback) {
        var dataRef = new Firebase(firebaseurl);
        $rootScope.loginObj = $firebaseSimpleLogin(dataRef);
        $rootScope.loginObj.$login('password', {
          email: email,
          password: pass,
          rememberMe: true
      }).then(function(user) {
          console.log('Logged in as: ', user.uid);
        }, function(error) {
          console.error('Login failed: ', error);
        });
    },
    logout: function(redirectPath) {
      $rootScope.loginObj.$logout();
      if(redirectPath) {
        $location.path(redirectPath);
      }
    }

  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the angularfire seed https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/ to add the following service:

```
.run(['loginService', '$rootScope', 'FBURL', function(loginService, $rootScope, FBURL) {
  // establish authentication
  $rootScope.auth = loginService.init('/admin/signin');
  $rootScope.FBURL = FBURL;
  }])
```

to get it to work.